# using nn.Cross entropy between outputs and target label

Tags: python, neural-network, torch, bert-language-model, cross-entropy

I use this code

## function to train the model

```
def train():
  
  model.train()

  total_loss, total_accuracy = 0, 0
  
  # empty list to save model predictions
  total_preds=[]
  
  # iterate over batches
  for step,batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    
    # progress update after every 50 batches.
    if step % 50 == 0 and not step == 0:
      print('  Batch {:>5,}  of  {:>5,}.'.format(step, len(train_dataloader)))

    # push the batch to gpu
    #batch = [r for r in batch]
 
    sent_id, mask, labels = batch['input_ids'],batch['attention_mask'],batch['labels']
    print(6)
    print(sent_id)
    print(mask)
    print(labels)
    print(batch['input_ids'].shape)
    print(batch['attention_mask'].shape)
    print(batch['labels'].shape)

    # clear previously calculated gradients 
    model.zero_grad() 
    print(7)       

    # get model predictions for the current batch
    preds = model(sent_id, mask)
    print(8)
    print(len(preds))
    print(len(labels))
    print(preds.size())
    
   
    preds =torch.argmax(preds, dim=1)
    preds =torch.argmax(preds, dim=1)
    print(preds)
    print(labels)

    # compute the loss between actual and predicted values
    loss = loss_fn(preds, labels)
    print(9)

    # add on to the total loss
    total_loss = total_loss + loss.item()
    print(10)

    # backward pass to calculate the gradients
    loss.backward()

    # clip the the gradients to 1.0. It helps in preventing the exploding gradient problem
  # clip the the gradients to 1.0. It helps in preventing the exploding gradient problem
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)

    # update parameters
    optimizer.step()

    # model predictions are stored on GPU. So, push it to CPU
    preds=preds.numpy()

    # append the model predictions
    total_preds.append(preds)

  # compute the training loss of the epoch
  avg_loss = total_loss / len(train_dataloader)
  
  # predictions are in the form of (no. of batches, size of batch, no. of classes).
  # reshape the predictions in form of (number of samples, no. of classes)
  total_preds  = np.concatenate(total_preds, axis=0)

  #returns the loss and predictions
  return avg_loss, total_preds
```

```
import torch.nn as nn

loss_fn=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.00001)
```

i got error in calculation of loss
preds
tensor([5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1,
0, 1, 4, 0, 5, 5, 4, 5, 0, 2, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1,
2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 0, 5])

labels
tensor([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3,
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0])
i used them in
loss=loss_fn(preds,labels)
error:

```
in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   2844     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2845         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2846     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
   2847 
   2848 

RuntimeError: Expected floating point type for target with class probabilities, got Long
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> RuntimeError: Expected floating point type for target with class
> probabilities, got Long

Error is pretty clear. You need to convert dtype of your target tensors to float. This has to do with what loss function you are using. Since you chose CE loss, you would end up with probabilities. And these probabilities are naturally float numbers. This means your targets should also be floats. For example, you may have a target tensor of a= [1, 0, 0, 1] You need to convert it to [1.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , 1.0]

You can use this table below to inspect all the types.

```
╔══════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║        Data type         ║             dtype             ║     CPU tensor     ║       GPU tensor        ║
╠══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 32-bit floating point    ║ torch.float32 or torch.float  ║ torch.FloatTensor  ║ torch.cuda.FloatTensor  ║
║ 64-bit floating point    ║ torch.float64 or torch.double ║ torch.DoubleTensor ║ torch.cuda.DoubleTensor ║
║ 16-bit floating point    ║ torch.float16 or torch.half   ║ torch.HalfTensor   ║ torch.cuda.HalfTensor   ║
║ 8-bit integer (unsigned) ║ torch.uint8                   ║ torch.ByteTensor   ║ torch.cuda.ByteTensor   ║
║ 8-bit integer (signed)   ║ torch.int8                    ║ torch.CharTensor   ║ torch.cuda.CharTensor   ║
║ 16-bit integer (signed)  ║ torch.int16 or torch.short    ║ torch.ShortTensor  ║ torch.cuda.ShortTensor  ║
║ 32-bit integer (signed)  ║ torch.int32 or torch.int      ║ torch.IntTensor    ║ torch.cuda.IntTensor    ║
║ 64-bit integer (signed)  ║ torch.int64 or torch.long     ║ torch.LongTensor   ║ torch.cuda.LongTensor   ║
║ Boolean                  ║ torch.bool                    ║ torch.BoolTensor   ║ torch.cuda.BoolTensor   ║
╚══════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

And for casting tensor to another dtype you can use something like

```
sample_tensor=sample_tensor.type(torch.FloatTensor)
```

or

```
sample_tensor=sample_tensor.to(torch.float )
```

(I am not sure if reassigning the tensors is necessary)

Comment: I tried this but i got this error

Comment: IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Comment: SO is not a debugging service, if you ask a question with a specific problem, and you get answer resolving it, please accept it, and ask a separate question if you know encounter new issues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you passing the wrong value of `preds` (tensor) to the `loss_fn` function. Look well and you will notice that you are passing the output of `preds = torch.argmax(preds, dim=1)` while you should pass the output of `preds = model(sent_id, mask)`. Doing so you are passing two tensors of dtype int64 to the loss function. However, the loss function (CrossEntropyLoss) expects a tensor of dtype float32 as its first parameter (i.e. the input parameter) -- see in 'Examples' at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html. Then you get a error: "Expected floating point type..."

To solve the problem you can compute the loss before changing the value of `preds` (i.e. before `preds = torch.argmax(preds, dim=1)`), as I do bellow. Or you could give another name to the output of `model()`, for instance `outp`, and pass it to your loss function, like: `loss_fn(outp, labels)`.

`# get model predictions for the current batch`

```
preds = model(sent_id, mask)
```

`# compute the loss between actual and predicted values`

```
loss = loss_fn(preds, labels)
preds =torch.argmax(preds, dim=1)
```